# Яке походження і інші значення слова "авенце"?

Tags: етимологія

Коли танцюєш народні танці, то вигук *авенце* слугує командою переходу до наступного партнеру по колу, тобто, якщо в колі *n* людей, то через *n* вигуків *авенце* пари стають такими ж як і на початку. [Ось приклад вживання](https://youtu.be/FIRiCBzjDGo?t=23).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Avancez - у бальних танцях команда "просуватися уперед" (французькою). Українське тлумачення знайшов у [примітці](https://www.ukrlib.com.ua/books/printit.php?tid=2745&page=125) до "Музея покинутих секретів" Оксани Забужко:

> Grandrond! Avancez! A trois temps! — Велике коло! Уперед! На раз-два-три! (франц.) — команди бального аранжера.